# Using shortcode in Post title

Tags: shortcode

I have lots of posts where I have current month with the post title.

When month ends, it's kind of annoying to change all the posts manually. So, I created a shortcode to show the current month.

I used *`add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );`* to execute the shortcode in title. It all works fine.

Problem is, in the meta title, the raw shortcode is showing instead of the output.

Any suggestions how I can work it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter for the title is `single_post_title`, you can do the same thing you do with `the_title`:

```
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Hi Milo,

Thank you very much. That works.

I just found out that I didn't have to use shortcode. I could use Yoast SEO. They have variables like %%currentmonth%%, %%currentyear%% which automatically shows the month and year. 

That's more convenient. 

Thanks anyways.